Constant flow of GET requests to root returning 404 response in Azure container app visible in App insights
We have an ASP.NET Core 8 API running in Azure container app. Recently we connected Azure application insights to it and we see a lot of requests being made to root of azure container app.
They are sent every 27 seconds and 3 seconds all the time.

Now at first I though this might be some kind of a probe making requests but all of them are disabled now.

We also have ngnix in front of our API responsible for routing but we can't see any traffic like this there so it seems to be something internal.
Any ideas what might be causing this or what can i check ? This isnt causing any visible issues but is flooding app insights with some unwanted data.
Edit:
I implemented root endpoint per @aaron suggestion. Added some logging for the headers etc.
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    app.MapGet("/", async context =>
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var headers = request.Headers.ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h.Value.ToString());

        var logger = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError("Request details: Remote IP: {RemoteIpAddress}, Path: {Path}, Headers: {Headers}",
            context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress,
            request.Path,
            headers);

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Root endpoint active");
    });

and this is what i'm getting now (redacted some internal info with *):
Request details: Remote IP: ::ffff:10.***.**.152, Path: /, 
Headers: [Host, ****-backend-api.whitefield-****.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io], 
[x-forwarded-for, 10.***.*.7], [x-envoy-internal, true], 
[x-request-id, *******-a7e3-427a-*******-*******], 
[x-envoy-expected-rq-timeout-ms, 1800000], 
[x-k8se-app-name, *******-backend-api--n76jimp], 
[x-k8se-app-namespace, k8se-apps], 
[x-k8se-protocol, http1], 
[x-k8se-app-kind, web], 
[x-ms-containerapp-name, *******-backend-api], 
[x-ms-containerapp-revision-name, *******-backend-api--n76jimp], 
[x-arr-ssl, true], 
[x-forwarded-proto, https]


Can you include your launchSettings and Program.cs in your question? It's hard to guess without seeing any code what's causing the calls. Alternatively can you implement a root endpoint and log the request details and see the user host and referrer?

@Aaron added root endpoint logs. So it kind of seems like the requests are internal but I'm still not sure what' sending them. My first guess would be the probes but it says they are disabled in the UI
